# Request does not support http method 'GET' error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, get, routes

I am getting next message on my WebApi controller request:

```
Message: "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
```

My action:

```
[HttpGet]
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
public EntityDTO Get(long entityId)
{


    return new Entity();
}
```

As you see, it already as `AcceptVerbs` and `GET` attributes.

My route in WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "EntityRoute",
     routeTemplate: "api/entity/{id}/{controller}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, controller = "Entity" }
);
```

This route fires for sure, I know it because my controller's Constructor fires.

Any ideas?

PS. There are lots of similar issues on StackOverflow, but for those issues adding proper attribute usually helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` parameter in your route does not match `entityId` in your method.  They need to match.

Comment: Thank you! xD
It just was a looong day for me) To tired to notice such thing
Silly me)